# Как очистить кеш игры на андроид автоматически кодом?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Как очистить кеш игры автоматически кодом перед закрытием игры ?

Я заметил что чем больше времени проводишь в игре,тем увеличивается кеш и данные игры.
И единственным способом избавиться от этого я вижу удалят кеш и данные автоматически.Когда пользователь закрывает игру в недавно используемых приложениях (Android).
Игра написана на С#,платформа Android,движок UNITY.
//Если есть другие варианты решения этой проблемы,пожалуйста поделитесь.

Comment: http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=49564 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод

```
Caching.ClearCache();
```

Он удаляет все содержимое AssetBundle, которое было кэшировано текущим приложением. Документация Unity по этому методу [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.ClearCache.html)